# How to get the file name with patterns one after the other

Tags: bash, shell, sh

How to get the name of the file with pattern `f-1,f-5,f-4,f-3,f-2`  one by one in a loop using the shell script.
I need to retreive the file names in the order of no's `1,2,3,4,5`

```
#!/bin/bash
ls f-* | sort | while read m
do
cat $m
done
```

Comment: explain what do you mean by get the file ?

Comment: Better add some sample input and output

Comment: Also, you may be able to solve your problem just by turning on shell debugging/trace with `set -vx` (and `set +vx`) to turn it off. Don't you mean `cat $f` ? ... Good luck.

Comment: They are automatically sorted

Comment: They are not automatically sorted. if I have f-10,f-20 included then it gets listed as f-1,f-10,f-2,f-20,f-3,f-4,f-5 with the 'ls' command

Comment: in bash u could use `ls -v f-*` to have them sorted 'naturally'

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in 1 2 3 4 5
do
  cat f-$i
done
```

or

```
ls f-* | sort | while read f
do
  cat $f
done
```

Comment: ls f-* | sort | while read f
do
  cat $f
done is not giving any o/p

Comment: i think he just wants the filename, if so:

    `ls f-* | while read f; do
        echo "$f"
    done`

Answer (score 0):

If it is just the filename you are after you have numerous options, a few below:

```
for f in f-*; do echo "$f"; done

ls f-* | while read f; do echo "$f"; done

#Total overkill for this example
find . -name "f-*" | while read f; do
  echo "$f"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
#!/bin/bash

echo ls: $(ls)
echo ""

seqmax=0
for file in $(ls ./f-* ); do
    char=$( echo $file | wc -c )
    if [ $char > $seqmax ];then
        seqmax=$char
    fi
done
i=0
for count in $(seq 1 1 $seqmax);do
    for file in $(ls | egrep "^f\-[0-9]{$count}$");do
        completearray[$i]=$file
        i=$(expr $i + 1 )
    done
done

echo ${completearray[@]}
```

and this should print out as follows.

```
$ ./script.sh
ls: f-1 f-15 f-16 f-2 f-3 f-one f-two g-1 g-2 g-3 script.sh

f-1 f-2 f-3 f-15 f-16
```